# Python script wait for button press before starting/stopping a separate python script

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, interrupts, signal

I've written a python script (shown below) which starts and stops another separate python script (datalogger) once a button is pressed. The datalogger script records logic levels (0 or 1) and stores them in a CSV. The recorded data should read 0 1 0 1 0 1 and so on.. However when I run the datalogger code by pressing the button the logic levels are recorded incorrectly i.e. 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1. This is because the button script as it is currently written is continuously 'looking' for a button press which is interrupting the datalogger script.

Therefore does anyone know how I can alter this script to make it wait for a button press and then proceed to either start or stop the datalogger script? Basically I don't want the button script to be doing anything until a button is pressed so it doesn't interrupt the datalogger. Thanks.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess, os
import signal

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO_switch = 24 # select pin to connect button
GPIO.setup(GPIO_switch, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:

    run = 0
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0 and run == 0:
            rpistr = "python3 /home/pi/Documents/DataloggerV2.py"
            p=subprocess.Popen(rpistr, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
            run=1
            while GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0:
                time.sleep(0.01)
        if GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0 and run == 1:
            run = 0
            os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            while GPIO.input(GPIO_switch)==0:
                time.sleep(0.01)


except KeyboardInterrupt:

    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as you asked before? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91152/python-script-datalogger-produces-different-data-when-run-from-a-separate-scri

Comment: No I was asking if anyone knew why my data was getting altered in that question. I've now realised what was causing it and am asking if anyone knows a solution (by making the script wait for a button press).

Comment: I'm not a python user, but what you want to use here are *event driven callbacks* -- functions you register with a library to be called when a specific event happens (you can implement that at a lower level by polling file descriptors, but I doubt you will need to do that in this case).  If you are not committed to programming it yourself, you might want to look into an existing tool such as `pigpiod`: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html  We have a tag here for questions about it, if you decide to go that route instead: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigpio